# Are long Drupal page loads normal?

Tags: drupal

We just had a design company redo our site from the ground up in Drupal and the first thing I notice is that the pages now take 5-6 seconds to load while they make 100+ separate requests to the server. Our old site loaded in 1.9s and only needed 27 server requests to get all its data.  Just clicking a different tab now in the Drupal menu takes 5 seconds to bring up the new page, while this only took 1.3 seconds on the old site. If the new site did a lot more than the old site I might understand, but it doesn't. It's basically the same, but "easier to maintain."

To my thinking, nothing tells you immediately that a site is professional like a landing page that just "snaps' in front of your eyes before you expect it. Ours is a site that sells products, so it's important to convey "professional" as soon as possible.  So this Drupal performance is a real disappointment. I recall reading that Amazon found that their revenues went up 1% for each 100ms they were able to shave off of their page load times. It's important, today, to get time down to the absolute minimum, to compete.

So are long load times just the way things are with Drupal, or does it seem like something is very wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Drupal ain't quick out of the box, and if you're on a shared host you might not have enough resources to do it justice. That said, any Drupal agency worth their salt will know how to set up caching to offset that. 5-6 seconds per page load sounds unreasonably high to me

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  It doesn't seem, though, like caching would help a first-time visitor. They've got to make everyone one of those 100+ round-trips to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal has pretty good caching and compressing tools built in,
It will automatically compress css and js files and will also serve cached pages (with no query to server)

See how to do it here:

https://drupal.org/node/326504